# Why did Jack allow Aku to escape?

Tags: samurai-jack

At the end of *Samurai Jack* S3E4 after fighting with Jack, Aku is in such a weakened state that he is no longer able to fly, nor even run efficiently, by the looks of it, he was reduced to just a... frog? Mouse? Barely capable of jumping away.. and Jack just let him get away, why? The scene in question is around 19:00 here: [Related scene](https://dai.ly/x6rbgv0?start=1135)

(I don't see why Jack couldn't have

> killed Aku 2 seasons early

in this very episode.)

Comment: Kill him... how? Have you ever tried to kill a mouse with a sword?

Comment: @jo1storm no, but i didn't spend my entire childhood practicing swordplay either :P (seems Jack was 25 years old when he entered the time portal)

Answer (score 0):

Killing Aku won't take him back to his home. Killing is not Jack's primary objective, he just wants to go home.

Comment: in S1E12 `Jack and the Gangsters`, Jack spent the entire episode trying to steal a magic crystal that Aku wanted (but was so well protected that even Aku couldn't steal it himself), so Jack could get an audience with Aku and kill him... i don't think that episode was about finding a time portal at all, it was all about killing Aku, if memory serves..?

Comment: quote from S1E12, Jack begging the gansters to give him an audience with Aku: ```Please understand, I have spent my lifetime preparing to come face-to-face with Aku, fulfilling this goal will forever change my life``` - another one: ```To stand in Aku's presence, i would consider no feat too great.```

Comment: i suppose it's possible that something happened after S1E12 and prior to S3E4, and that in S1E12 he really wanted to kill Aku, and by the time of S3E4 he *no longer* wanted to kill Aku, but that sounds unlikely to me (especially since he killed Aku in S5)